# Startup tomcat 9 on CentOS 7 with port 80 through systemctl

Tags: tomcat, centos

I have a situation, where I cannot access tomcat through browser with port 80. I start the tomcat service through `systemctrl start tomcat`.
But if I start through `./startup.sh` it works.

The file `server.xml` has already modified.

can anyone help me with this situation?

Btw, when I restart the server, the tomcat will not automatically start. The command `systemctl enable tomcat` has already called.

- CentOS 7
- Tomcat 9
- MySQL

Did I missed something?

Comment: You need to try to diagnose what happens. Does tomcat even start when you run `systemctl start tomcat` ? Do you get any errors in any relevant log files ? Check also output from `systemctl status tomcat`  How have you installed tomcat ? The standard tomcat distribution doesn't come/install files needed to manage it through systemctl - so that can be a source of error if the service files for tomcat is not made properly.

Comment: Yes, when I run `systemctl start tomcat` it started, but i cannot access it (because the port is 80 , may be?). I know it from `systemctl status tomcat`. Before I changed the port from 8080 to 80, it worked with `systemctl start tomcat`. I read in many website, that port 80 (port 1 - 1024) has privileged and just only access with sudo, Correct me if I'm wrong.